# How to set initial value in a dynamic list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that obtains the details of an existing record (via ajax) from a back end database. After the record is retrieved, the jsp page is populated with the details, including the value of an item from a dynamically populated list.

My problem comes when I need to set the value into the drop down list as the initial value. The list always defaults to the first item, even after I've set the value explicitly.

I've tried hard coding the entire list (and not using any filters) into the page, which allows setting the initial value to work, so I can safely assume the problem lies with how I'm populating the filtered list. I just can't seem to find a working solution (and displaying the entire list to the user is not an option).

```js
function getRecord() {

    $.ajax({
          url: "<s:url action='getRecords'/>",
          type: "POST",
          data: jQuery.param(searchObj),
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var _data = $.parseJSON(data);
            var record = _data["record"];

            $("#recordID").val(record["ID"]);
            $("#country").val(record["country"]);

            /* populate the country specific list */
            populateList(record["country"]);

            /* set the selected item in the list */
            $("#countryItems").val(record["countryItem"]); // doesn't work
            $("#countryItems").prop("selected", record["country"]); // doesn't work either
            $("#countryItems option [value='" + record["countryItem"] + "']").prop("selected", "selected"); // still doesn't work

            // do other stuff here
          }
        }

        function populateList(country) {

          $.ajax({
            url: "<s:url action='populateList'/>",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              country: country
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              var _data = $.parseJSON(data);
              var listMap = _data["listMap"]; // filtered list

              // remove existing list
              $('#countryItems option').remove();

              // append new list
              $.map(listMap, function(k, v) {
                $('#countryItems').append(new Option(k, v));
              });
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that record["countryItem"] matches any of the actual values in countryItems options list?

Comment: `$("#countryItems option[value='"+ record["countryItem"] +"']").prop("selected", "selected")` notice there is no space between `option` and `[value..`

Comment: @Slava.K Yes, I have a `console.log` on both the filtered list and record["countryItem"]. The returned values are correct. @xkcd149 Okay I tried it, still doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: You have to set prop value to a boolean value. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add some closure to this. Thanks to everyone who tried to help. Unfortunately, none of the suggestions worked (still don't know why). My colleague eventually came up with a more convoluted solution that did work, so we had to settle for that.

```
 function getRecord() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "<s:url action='getRecords'/>",
      type: "POST",
      data: jQuery.param(searchObj),
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var _data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var record = _data["record"];

        $("#recordID").val(record["ID"]);
        $("#country").val(record["country"]);

        /* populate the country specific list */
        // pass in the selected record as well
        populateList(record["country"], record["countryItem"]);


        // do other stuff here
      }
    }

 function populateList(country, selectedItem) {

      $.ajax({
        url: "<s:url action='populateList'/>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          country: country
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          var _data = $.parseJSON(data);
          var listMap = _data["listMap"]; // filtered list

          // remove existing list
          $('#countryItems option').remove();

          // append new list
          $.map(listMap, function(k, v) {

                if(v == selectedItem) {
                    // add the selected indicator together with the option
                    option='<option value="'+ v +'" selected="selected">'+ k +'</option>'
                }
                else{
                    // just add the option
                    option='<option value="'+v+'">'+k+'</option>'
                }

                $('#countryItems').append(option);
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

I'll mark this as correct, since it's the only solution that worked for me, but I'll upvote @Patrick Vogt 's answer, because it's the one that should work for most other people who don't have whatever obscure problem that I've got.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to select the option and then set the selected property to true value.

`$('option item selector').prop('selected', true);`

Comment: How does the exact syntax work? `$("option[value='"+ record["countryItem"] + "']").prop('selected', true);`?

Comment: @sml485 I have not tested it but it might work. If this does not work, you can try the following selector: `$("#countryItems option[value='" + record["countryItem"] + "']").prop("selected", true);`